# Performing user authentication in Java EE / JSF / EJB, on JBoss

Tags: security, jsf, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I found little documentation on this specific case, however I have found many tutoriels that uses GlassFish to create security realm + no EJB.

However my web application is running on

- jboss wildfly 8 server
- Having a separate EJB project for JPA entities and ejb sessions for services
- Another JSF java EE web project (no maven no spring) that having managedbeans / xhtml view pages...

In my database I have a user Table that contains: username,pwd(plaintxt),role

What I want to achieve is to find a way to do authentication so each Role will have access to specifics views + add encryption over ssl if possible

Comment: The proposed similar question DOES NOT respond to my full question, I asked on how to implement roles + add encryption over SSL, in other words I am asking if there is a framework that can establish both of these features such as what we simply do when using a glassfish server.

Comment: SSL or not does not make a difference...So in that regard it is a valid duplicate